# Default Android Keyboard Positioning

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm designing a kiosk for Android with a very tall screen. The default keyboard docked at the bottom is rather awkward given that most of the visual action happens near the top of the screen. How difficult is it to reposition the keyboard exactly where I want it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have any code or attempts at solving this already? If so, please add them to your question; it'll help other users answer.

Comment: Improve your question, what's "kiosk"? think about adding a screenshot or some code that help explaining what you are trying to do and what's the problem you are facing.